# How to avoid clubbing of two rows for the same record while doing SUM and GROUP BY in PostgreSql

Tags: sql, postgresql

There are 4 tables in general
"product","projecteddata","payoutblock" ,"users"

product

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.product
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('product_id_seq'::regclass),
    "productType" character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    amount numeric NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'::numeric,
    "startDate" date NOT NULL
)
```

projecteddata

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.projecteddata
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('projecteddata'::regclass),
    "productType" character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    amount numeric NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'::numeric,
    "startDate" date NOT NULL,
    "systemGeneratedStartDate" date NOT NULL,
    "systemGeneratedEndDate" date NOT NULL,
    "productId" integer,
    CONSTRAINT "FK_c6c14f315490aceb2f7a9ffb3ed" FOREIGN KEY ("productId")
        REFERENCES public.product (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

payoutblock

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.payoutblock
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('payoutblock_id_seq'::regclass),
    "productId" integer,
    "payeeId" uuid, 
    CONSTRAINT "FK_1bc960a61d22c0daf3efd691d70" FOREIGN KEY ("productId")
        REFERENCES public.product (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT "FK_e6f4e4b0f0750910b39ec67f816" FOREIGN KEY ("payeeId")
        REFERENCES public.users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

users

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.users
(
    id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    CONSTRAINT "PK_a3ffb1c0c8416b9fc6f907b7433" PRIMARY KEY (id),
)
```

**Sample Input**

```
INSERT INTO public.product(
    id, "productType", amount, "startDate")
    VALUES (1, 'ABCD', 100, '2022-10-02'),
    VALUES (2, 'XYZ', 100, '2022-12-14');
```

```
INSERT INTO public.payoutblock(
    id,"productId", "payeeId")
    VALUES (1, 1, '0005c2b6-29f2-491f-8565-c30567f232f9'),
        VALUES (2, 1 , 'ec5e7cbb-2f82-4b05-8135-73746b59afb0'),
    VALUES (3, 2, '0005c2b6-29f2-491f-8565-c30567f232f9');
```

```
INSERT INTO public.users(
    id
    VALUES ('0005c2b6-29f2-491f-8565-c30567f232f9'),
    ('ec5e7cbb-2f82-4b05-8135-73746b59afb0');
```

```
INSERT INTO public.projecteddata(
    id, "productType", amount, "startDate", "systemGeneratedStartDate", "systemGeneratedEndDate",
    "productId")
    VALUES (1, 'ABCD', 100, '2022-10-02', '2022-10-01', '2022-10-31', 1),
    VALUES (2, 'ABCD', 100, '2022-10-02', '2022-11-01', '2022-11-30', 1),
    VALUES (3, 'XYZ', 100, '2022-12-14', '2022-12-01', '2022-12-31', 2),
    VALUES (4, 'ABCD', 100, '2022-10-02', '2022-12-01', '2022-12-31', 1),
    VALUES (5, 'XYZ', 100, '2022-12-14', '2023-01-01','2023-01-31', 2),
    VALUES (6, 'ABCD', 100, '2022-10-02', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-31', 1),
    VALUES (7, 'XYZ', 100, '2022-12-14', '2023-02-01', '2023-02-28', 2),
    VALUES (8, 'ABCD', 100, '2022-10-02', '2023-02-01', '2023-02-28', 1);
```

I am trying to run this query:

```
SELECT sum(rpd."amount"),to_char(rpd."systemGeneratedStartDate", 'YYYY-MM-DD') as "systemGeneratedStartDate",
            to_char(rpd."systemGeneratedEndDate", 'YYYY-MM-DD') as "systemGeneratedEndDate"
            FROM "projecteddata" rpd
            left join public.product rp
            on rpd."productId" = rp."id"
            left join public.payoutblock pb
            on pb."productId" = rp."id"
            WHERE "systemGeneratedStartDate" >= '2022-10-01' AND "systemGeneratedStartDate" < '2024-04-01' 
             AND (pb."payeeId" IN ( 'ec5e7cbb-2f82-4b05-8135-73746b59afb0' , '0005c2b6-29f2-491f-8565-c30567f232f9' )) 
            GROUP BY "systemGeneratedStartDate","systemGeneratedEndDate",rp."id"
                    ORDER BY "systemGeneratedStartDate" ASC
```

but not getting the desired result

Current Output

| sum | systemGeneratedStartDate | systemGeneratedEndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | "2022-12-01" | "2022-12-31" |
| 200 | "2023-02-01" | "2023-02-28" |
| 200 | "2023-03-01" | "2023-03-31" |
| 200 | "2023-05-01" | "2023-05-31" |
| 200 | "2023-06-01" | "2023-06-30" |
| 200 | "2023-07-01" | "2023-07-31" |
| 200 | "2023-08-01" | "2023-08-31" |
| 200 | "2023-09-01" | "2023-09-30" |

Also tried by adding payeeId in the group by clause

```
SELECT sum(rpd."amount"),to_char(rpd."systemGeneratedStartDate", 'YYYY-MM-DD') as "systemGeneratedStartDate",
            to_char(rpd."systemGeneratedEndDate", 'YYYY-MM-DD') as "systemGeneratedEndDate",pb."payeeId"
            FROM "projecteddata" rpd
            left join public.product rp
            on rpd."productId" = rp."id"
            left join public.payoutblock pb
            on pb."productId" = rp."id"
            WHERE "systemGeneratedStartDate" >= '2022-10-01' AND "systemGeneratedStartDate" < '2024-04-01' 
            AND rpd."status" = 0 AND (pb."payeeId" IN ( 'ec5e7cbb-2f82-4b05-8135-73746b59afb0' , '0005c2b6-29f2-491f-8565-c30567f232f9' )) 
            GROUP BY "systemGeneratedStartDate","systemGeneratedEndDate",rp."id",pb."payeeId"
                    ORDER BY "systemGeneratedStartDate" ASC
```

Output

| sum | systemGeneratedStartDate | systemGeneratedEndDate | payeeId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | "2022-12-01" | "2022-12-31" | "0005c2b6-29f2-491f-8565-c30567f232f9" |
| 100 | "2022-12-01" | "2022-12-31" | "ec5e7cbb-2f82-4b05-8135-73746b59afb0" |
| 100 | "2023-02-01" | "2023-02-28" | "0005c2b6-29f2-491f-8565-c30567f232f9" |
| 100 | "2023-02-01" | "2023-02-28" | "ec5e7cbb-2f82-4b05-8135-73746b59afb0" |
| 100 | "2023-03-01" | "2023-03-31" | "0005c2b6-29f2-491f-8565-c30567f232f9" |
| 100 | "2023-03-01" | "2023-03-31" | "ec5e7cbb-2f82-4b05-8135-73746b59afb0" |
| 100 | "2023-05-01" | "2023-05-31" | "0005c2b6-29f2-491f-8565-c30567f232f9" |
| 100 | "2023-05-01" | "2023-05-31" | "ec5e7cbb-2f82-4b05-8135-73746b59afb0" |
| 100 | "2023-06-01" | "2023-06-30" | "0005c2b6-29f2-491f-8565-c30567f232f9" |
| 100 | "2023-06-01" | "2023-06-30" | "ec5e7cbb-2f82-4b05-8135-73746b59afb0" |
| 100 | "2023-07-01" | "2023-07-31" | "0005c2b6-29f2-491f-8565-c30567f232f9" |
| 100 | "2023-07-01" | "2023-07-31" | "ec5e7cbb-2f82-4b05-8135-73746b59afb0" |
| 100 | "2023-08-01" | "2023-08-31" | "0005c2b6-29f2-491f-8565-c30567f232f9" |
| 100 | "2023-08-01" | "2023-08-31" | "ec5e7cbb-2f82-4b05-8135-73746b59afb0" |
| 100 | "2023-09-01" | "2023-09-30" | "0005c2b6-29f2-491f-8565-c30567f232f9" |
| 100 | "2023-09-01" | "2023-09-30" | "ec5e7cbb-2f82-4b05-8135-73746b59afb0" |

> This is happening because payoutblock contains two payeeId for which the sum is getting clubbed.

> What is required is the sum to not get clubbed even if two payeedId's are there for one payoutblock

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

| sum | systemGeneratedStartDate | systemGeneratedEndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | "2022-12-01" | "2022-12-31" |
| 100 | "2023-02-01" | "2023-02-28" |
| 100 | "2023-03-01" | "2023-03-31" |
| 100 | "2023-05-01" | "2023-05-31" |
| 100 | "2023-06-01" | "2023-06-30" |
| 100 | "2023-07-01" | "2023-07-31" |
| 100 | "2023-08-01" | "2023-08-31" |
| 100 | "2023-09-01" | "2023-09-30" |

[Link to the entity diagram][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nll7Q.png

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "to club two rows"?

Comment: Can you share sample input data?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe , for example, for a particular product (with amount 100), the payoutblock can have mulitple payeeIds. But while SUMMING, I want the amount to not get added twice(200)/thrice(300) depending on number of payeeId for the same product, instead, the amount (100) should get summed up.

Comment: @lemon hey, I have updated the question with sample input scripts

Comment: I've noticed in your input data there's some product which has amount = 200 value. Why they don't appear in your expected output? Is it a partial output?

Comment: @lemon I have updated the scripts. That was an error :)

Comment: Check my answer below and try it in your DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
left join public.payoutblock pb on pb."productId" = rp."id"
```

try something like:

```
left join (select distinct productID
           from public.payoutblock
           where "payeeId" IN ( 'ec5e7cbb-2f82-4b05-8135-73746b59afb0' ,
                                '0005c2b6-29f2-491f-8565-c30567f232f9' )
          ) pb on pb."productId" = rp."id"
```

and then in your main WHERE clause you would have:

```
WHERE pb."productId" is not null
```

or, potentially, just make the join an INNER rather than LEFT

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, I will definitely try implementing it :)

Comment: it did not work out, the result is still the same. 
Also if you can check the demo link 
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nsC1ejhdbBsvrWsMwcjCEv/0